# is binomial congruence given in article true or false?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, congruences

I'm just reading a [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Mihoubi/mihoubi4.pdf) which, on its page 3, Application 8, claims the following:

$$\binom{k+sp}{j}\equiv\binom{k}{j}\pmod{p}$$

where $p\ge 1$, $s\ge 1$, $k\ge 1$ and $p\not\mid j$ (actually, it claims that this holds even in a generalized setting where binomial coefficients are subscripted by some $q$ for which $q=1$ retrieves the ordinary binomial coefficients).

However, when I let $k=5$, $j=4$, $s=1$, $p=3$, then

$$\binom{k+sp}{j}=\binom{8}{4}=70\not\equiv 5=\binom{5}{4}=\binom{k}{j}\pmod{p}.$$

Can anyone confirm that I'm right or am I completely missing something? (And if I am in fact correct, the other congruence indicated in Application 8 is probably false, too?)

Comment: I think that is not the claim in the paper. There is a subscript $q$ after $\binom{\cdots}{\cdots}$ in the paper.

Comment: @Tunococ Yes, did you read what I wrote in the question about the $q$?

Comment: Sorry. I did read, but I didn't really understand what the subscript mean. Now I know what you're saying. If the paper makes the claim without any extra restrictions, it does seem wrong.

Comment: That subscript $q$ stands for the so-called [Gaussian binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-binomial).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas No, it doesn't, but thanks (making a wild guess doesn't seem to be a good strategy :D). I'm interested only in the case $q=1$, which retrieves the ordinary binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions are missing, which your example violates.  You need to assume $0\leq s,k,j<p$.  I'm not seeing anything in the paper in question which would enforce this (they do seem intent on $k,j$ simply being coprime). So there's either a convention that enforces this that's been overlooked/unstated, or there is an error in the paper.

As it turns out, the $q=1$ case for your example boils down to a special case of [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).  That special case being that for any prime $p$ and non-negative integers $n,n_0,r,r_0$ that are all less than $p$ we have

$${{np+n_0}\choose{rp+r_0}}\equiv {n\choose r}{n_0\choose r_0}\mod p.$$

For your example, with $p=3$ you should instead be looking at
$$70={8\choose 4}={{2p+2}\choose{p+1}}\equiv {2\choose 1}{2\choose 1}=4\equiv 1\mod p.$$
Which is true.

Expressions of the form $np+n_0$ for such $n,n_0$ are simply the base $p$ expansion of a number between $0$ and $p^2-1$.  The fully general form of Lucas's theorem applies to arbitrary base $p$ expansions.  If you apply proper base $p$ expansions to the results of your paper things might work out, but I've not yet attempted to consider if this fixes the $q\neq 1$ case.

Comment: You don't need any assumptions on $s$.